# JS - How to calculate all possible +, -, ÷, × math operation for 4 specific numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, combinations

Let's say I have these four numbers: [1, 5, 3, 8].
And I want to check which of the math operations equals to 10. Also the order of the numbers matters, meaning the first number should always be the first index in the array and so on.

For example:

- (1 + 5) ÷ 3 + 8
- 1 x 5 - 3 + 8

How can I achieve this?

Honestly, I have no idea how I should approach this. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Exhaustive search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create an Expr class to represent expressions, which consist of two operands (which may be simple numbers or other expressions) and an operator. This provides convenience functions for evaluating the expression and outputting the expression as a string.

In the simple case, where there are only two expressions x and y, we return all possible combinations x+y, x-y, x*y, x÷y.

Then, when there are more expression operands, we find (all combinations of (x operator y) with ...z), and (x operator (all combinations of y with ...z))

```js
class Op {
  constructor(symbol,func) { this.symbol = symbol; this.func = func; }
  invoke(x,y) { return this.func(
    x instanceof Expr ? x.eval() : x,
    y instanceof Expr ? y.eval() : y)
  }
  toString() { return this.symbol }
}
const ops = [
  new Op('+', (x,y)=>x+y), new Op('-', (x,y)=>x-y),
  new Op('*', (x,y)=>x*y), new Op('÷', (x,y)=>x/y),
]

class Expr {
  constructor(x,op,y){ this.x=x; this.op=op; this.y=y }
  eval() { return this.op.invoke(this.x, this.y) }
  toString() { return `(${this.x}${this.op}${this.y})` }
}

const f = (x,y,...z) =>
  !z.length ? ops.map(op=>new Expr(x,op,y)) :
  [...f(x,y).flatMap(expr=>f(expr, ...z)),
   ...f(y,...z).flatMap(expr=>f(x, expr))]

// show all combinations
console.log(f(...[1, 5, 3, 8]).map(i=>i.toString()))

// show only combinations that evaluate to 10
console.log(f(...[1, 5, 3, 8]).filter(i=>i.eval()===10).map(i=>i.toString()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Construct the set of possible results for each contiguous range of the input values.

If a range has a single number, then the only mathematical expression constructible is the number itself.

Otherwise, if you have a range a[i], a[i+1], ..., a[j] then for each k from i+1 to j, find the set of possible results constructible from a[i], a[i+1], ..., a[k-1], and the set of possible results constructible from a[k], a[k+1], ..., a[j], then combine them using +, -, * and / in every possible combination.

For example, for `[1, 5, 3, 8]` there's three ways of breaking up the sequence:

```
 [1] [5, 3, 8]
 [1, 5], [3, 8]
 [1, 5, 3], [8]
```

Working through just the second line: `[1, 5]` can produce `{1+5, 1-5, 1*5, 1/5}` and `[3, 8]` can produce `{3+8, 3-8, 3*8, 3/8}`, so this gives `{(1+5)+(3+8), (1+5)-(3+8), (1+5)*(3+8), (1+5)/(3+8), (1-5)+(3+8), (1-5)-(3+8), ..., (1/5)+(3/8), (1/5)-(3/8), (1/5)*(3/8), (1/5)/(3/8)}`.

This is workable as-is if you only have 4 input numbers, but if you have more then you will find you can memoize or use dynamic programming to avoid computing the same things repeatedly. It will always be exponential time though, since the range of constructible values grows exponentially.

Comment: +1. An important implicit observation here is that these operators are all *binary* -- they take two operands -- and so each expression is built out of two sub-expressions. For example, the OP's first example, "(1 + 5) ÷ 3 + 8", means "((1 + 5) ÷ 3) + 8": it's (1 + 5) ÷ 3 plus 8, where (1 + 5) ÷ 3 is (1 + 5) divided by 3.